How to calculate surface speed from wheel size and rpm where the result is in units of speed?
I have a wheel with a diameter of 1mm that is rotating at 1rpm. To calculate the surface speed of the wheel, I think can use the expression $$1\text{mm} * \pi * 1\text{rpm}$$ and that gets me the result $$5.236×10^-5 \text{m rev/s (meter revolutions per second)}$$
I believe this is the correct result, but it isn't in the units I am expecting. I am trying to work out if there are additional units I can enter into the expression so that a tool such as Wolfram Alpha which respects units would give me the result with normal speed units and no angular component (e.g. m/s).
It is possible to just ignore the result units and use the value, but the intent of my work is to generally respect units in a parsing system so putting in a special case for this isn't the ideal solution for me.
It feels like PI should be effectively cancelling out the angular component/dimension of the unit but perhaps that doesn't make sense.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

$$\frac{1 ~\text{revolution}}{\text{minute}} \times \frac{\pi ~\text{mm}}{\text{revolution}} = \frac{\pi ~\text{mm}}{\text{minute}}.$$
See also the "simple cases" section of the dimensional analysis article.
